# Eclipse, equinox and product file, resolve missing features

Tags: plugins, eclipse-rcp, equinox, missing-features

Good morning,

I am trying to start ad RCP application.
The "Contents" section of the product file show something is missing.
The list shown clicking the "Add" button does not contain what misses (for example org.eclipse.rcp).

How can I upgrade eclipse configuration to resolve?

[SOLVED]: switch to Eclipse RCP version resolved the first problem.

Now, as you can see in the second image, I can't start product file because of bundles dependency errors (org.eclipse.m2e.core requires com.google.guava).

Any ideas to solve?

Thank you so much,
   Emilio

[image: Eclipse RCP application missing features]

[image: OSGI org.eclipse.m2e.core bundle dependency not satisfied]

Comment: Either the features are not in your target platform or the versions don't match. It is usually best not to specify versions in the product file.

Comment: Thank you for response.
I removed version and, now, only two features are marked as missing:

org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient4.feature and 
org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient4.ssl.feature

How I add them?

Comment: It looks like those features are not included in current Eclipse builds. Eclipse 4.11 (2019-03) was the last to include them.